# Find common records in many to many relation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a many to many relation - `OrderPostions` between tables (`Orders` and `Urls`) and would like to get a sum of all of the Urls that are in `Orders`. Each order can have many urls and each url can be in many orders, each order belongs to client. The aim of this query is to find how many urls are shared between clients.

What I have so far is:

```
select sum(nb.byUrl)
from
(  select count(U.UrlId) as byUrl
   from Urls U
   inner join OrderPositions OP on U.UrlId = OP.UrlId
   inner join Orders O on O.OrderId = OP.OrderId
   group by (U.Url)
   having count(OP.OrderId) >= 2
) nb
```

And the sqlfiddle with schema is here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/824b7/44

Comment: Sample data and desired results *as text tables in the question* would really help.  I don't see what the query has to do with the question.

Comment: Sample data and schema are in provided link to sqlfiddle. The provided query sum the data but I am not totally sure that is doing its job correctly.

Comment: Can you elaborate bit more what exactly you want by giving example using the data you provided in sqlfiddle ? What is the expected out come?

Comment: Expected outcome is 7 in provided data but I am not sure if all of the possibilties are cover by this solution.